# Resolving "The terminal shell CWD "/mnt/c/Users/User/Downloads/IG-Bot/C:\Users\User\VSC" does not exist error message

Tags: python, linux, powershell, visual-studio-code

I was trying to build an Instagram Bot using visual studio code python and WSL, (Windows Subsystem for Linux) when I decided to begin by opening a terminal window in Visual Studio Code and I got the error

> "The terminal shell CWD
>   "/mnt/c/Users/User/Downloads/IG-Bot/C:\Users\User\VSC" does not exist"

message not sure if its either how I installed the plugins on visual studio or how Integrated The subsystem using powershell.

Comment: Unless you are using a bash terminal, `/mnt/c` will not exist and windows paths also use `\ ` instead of `/`. Is there something wrong here: /mnt/c/Users/User/Downloads/IG-Bot/ **C:\Users\User\VSC**?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the [WSL - Remote extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) as that will make sure VS Code acts like you're working under Linux. Otherwise you end up in a situation like you're in where VS Code thinks you're trying to work under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue when connecting to a remote host via SSH. The connection would establish correctly, I opened a folder and could see the files, but as soon as I tried to open a terminal via the "Terminal" > "New Terminal" option, it would show me this error message.

Reason for it was that in the meantime I deleted the folder which I originally opened in my SSH session. As I wanted to open a new terminal, it tried opening the CWD of the VSCODE project, which was the folder that I deleted in a seperate terminal session.

Restarting the SSH session and opening an existing folder, such as "/root", solved the issue for me.